# The derivative of $f$ at $x_0$ as the limit when $J\to x_0$ of the ratios $|f(J)|/|J|$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be differentiable on an interval $I$ and let $x_0$ be an interior point of $I$. Make precise the following statement and prove it: $$\lim_{J \to x_0} \frac{|f(J)|}{|J|} = |f '(x_0)|$$

using the definition of limits where $$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} = f'(x_0).$$

Comment: consider $f(x) = x^2$, and $x_0 = 1$. Then $$\lim_{J \rightarrow x_0} \frac{|x^2|}{|x|} = \lim_{J \rightarrow 1} |J| = 1 \neq 2 = |f'(1)|$$so maybe you want a different statement?

Comment: using the definition of limits i think. where f(x) - f(x0)/x - x0

Comment: The first statement doesn't make sense as it stated. But one can understand what is meant to be here. For example $J\to x_0$ is means interval $J$ contracts to the point $x_0$, $|f(J)|$ and $|J|$ means lengths of respective intervals.

Comment: Maybe you meant $|J|\to 0$ where $J$ is an interval containing $x_0$?

Comment: Please consider rewriting your post to mention what you tried and to cancel all those imperatives.

Comment: This seems to be exercise 7.2.26 from the book [Elementary Real Analysis](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/) by Brian S. Thomson,Judith B. Bruckner,Andrew M. Bruckner; [p.278](http://books.google.com/books?id=vA9d57GxCKgC&pg=PA278).

Comment: The original version appears to be identical to [this Yahoo! Answers question](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121031205358AAYPjs8), errors and all.

Answer (score 2):

For every interval $J$, $f(J)=\{f(x)\mid x\in J\}$. Assume that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ with $f'(x_0)=c$ and assume without loss of generality that $c\geqslant0$. For every $\varepsilon\gt0$, there exists $\alpha\lt x_0\lt \beta$ such that for every $\alpha\lt x\lt\beta$, 
$$
f(x_0)+c(x-x_0)-\varepsilon|x-x_0|\leqslant f(x)\leqslant f(x_0)+c(x-x_0)+\varepsilon|x-x_0|.
$$
In particular, for every $J=(a,b)\subseteq(\alpha,\beta)$, $(c_\varepsilon,d_\varepsilon)\subseteq f(J)\subseteq(a_\varepsilon,b_\varepsilon)$, with 
$$
a_\varepsilon=f(x_0)+c(a-x_0)-\varepsilon(x_0-a),\qquad
b_\varepsilon=f(x_0)+c(b-x_0)+\varepsilon(b-x_0),
$$
and
$$
c_\varepsilon=f(x_0)+c(a-x_0)+\varepsilon(x_0-a),\qquad
d_\varepsilon=f(x_0)+c(b-x_0)-\varepsilon(b-x_0).
$$
Thus $d_\varepsilon-c_\varepsilon\leqslant|f(J)|\leqslant b_\varepsilon-a_\varepsilon$, that is, $(c-\varepsilon)(b-a)\leqslant|f(J)|\leqslant(c+\varepsilon)(b-a)$. Since $b-a=|J|$, this shows that 
$$
\left|\frac{|f(J)|}{|J|}-c\right|\leqslant\varepsilon,
$$
for every interval $J\subseteq(\alpha,\beta)$. In this sense,
$$
\lim_{J\to x_0}\frac{|f(J)|}{|J|}=c.
$$

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be exercise 7.2.26 from the book [Elementary Real
Analysis](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/) by Brian S.
Thomson,Judith B. Bruckner,Andrew M. Bruckner;
[p.278](http://books.google.com/books?id=vA9d57GxCKgC&pg=PA278).

This exercise is contained in Section 7.2.3 The Derivative as a
Magnification, where authors provide the following motivation for the
derivative at a point.

> If $J$ is a sufficiently small interval having $x_0$ as an endpoint, then the ratio
>   $|f(J)|/|J|$ is approximately $|f'(x_0)|$, the approximation becoming "exact in
>   the limit." Thus $|f'(x_0)|$ can be viewed as a "magnification factor" of small
>   intervals containing the point $x_0$.

---

With this motivation we can formalize the above statement as: For very
$\varepsilon>0$ and there exists $\delta>0$ such that for any interval
$J$, such that $|J|<\delta$ and $J$ has $x_0$ as the endpoint, the inequality
$$\left|\frac{|f(J)|}{|J|}-|f'(x_0)|\right|<\varepsilon$$
holds.

By the definition of derivative you have $\delta>0$ such that
$|x-x_0|\le\delta$ implies
$|\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-f'(x_0)|<\varepsilon$.
But this also implies
$$\left|\frac{|f(x)-f(x_0)|}{|x-x_0|}-|f'(x_0)|\right|<\varepsilon.$$

If $J$ is interval of the form $[x_0,x]$ with $x_0-x<\delta$ and $y\in J$ then
$$\left|\frac{|f(y)-f(x_0)|}{y-x_0}-|f'(x_0)|\right|<\varepsilon\\
\left||f(y)-f(x_0)|-|f'(x_0)|(y-x_0)\right|<\varepsilon(y-x_0)\\
|f'(x_0)|(y-x_0)-\varepsilon(y-x_0) < |f(y)-f(x_0)| < |f'(x_0)|(y-x_0)+\varepsilon(y-x_0)\\
f(x_0)-|f'(x_0)|(y-x_0)-\varepsilon(y-x_0) < f(y) <  f(x_0)+|f'(x_0)|(y-x_0)+\varepsilon(y-x_0)
$$
Considering the rightmost point of the interval (which fulfills $x-x_0=|J|$) we see that
$$|f(J)| \ge |f(x)-f(x_0)| \ge |f'(x_0)||J|-\varepsilon|J|.$$
On the other hand, for any $y,y'\in J$ we have
$f(y)-f(y')< |f'(x_0)|(y-y')+\varepsilon(y-x_0)+\varepsilon(y'-x_0) \le |f'(x_0)||J|+2\varepsilon|J|$.
This implies
$$|f(J)|\le |f'(x_0)||J|+2\varepsilon|J|.$$
Together we have
$$\left|\frac{|f(J)|}{|J|}-|f'(x_0)|\right| < 2\varepsilon$$
for any interval $J$ which has endpoint $x_0$ and small enough length.